# showing map $\mathbb{RP}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^5$ is smooth embedding

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Condider $f:\mathbb{RP}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^5$ given by
$$f[x,y,z]=[x^2,y^2,z^2,yz,xz,xy]$$
I would like to show that $f$ is a smooth embedding, meaning that it is a smooth immersion and a topological embedding. For $f$ to be a smooth immersion, I need the differential to be injective. This is given by
$$df=\begin{pmatrix}
2x & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2y & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2z\\
0 & z & y\\
z & 0 & x\\
y & x & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
However, I am not sure how homogeneous coordinates influence this. Do I need to use charts rather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use charts. What you have written is not $df$, it is the differential of a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^6$. But we can restrict $f$ to an affine chart
$$ f[x,y,1] = [x^2,y^2,1,y,x,xy] $$
and compute its differential as a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^5$
$$ df = \begin{bmatrix} 2x & 0\\ 0 & 2y\\ 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\\ y & x \end{bmatrix} $$

Edit: Here's how to finish the argument. By computing the differential you can show that $f$ is a smooth immersion. Next we show that $f$ is injective. Suppose that $f[x,y,z] = f[a,b,c]$. Then $x^2=a^2,y^2=b^2,$ and $z^2=c^2$ (since e.g. $x^2=-a^2$ is impossible) so $x=\pm a, y=\pm b, z=\pm c$. Now use the equations $xy=ab,yz=bc,xz=ac$ to see that either $x=a,y=b,$ and $z=c$ or $x=-a, y=-b$, and $z=-c$. In either case $[x,y,z]=[a,b,c]$ so $f$ is injective.

Now $f$ is an injective smooth immersion defined on compact manifold, [so](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111112/condition-that-a-local-homeomorphism-be-a-covering-map) it is an embedding.

Comment: So I know that if a map between manifolds is locally a smooth embedding, then it is globally as well. But I still don't understand how I can use the charts to show this particular map is a smooth embedding.

Comment: Being a smooth immersion is a local property, so you can verify it by checking on each chart. Can you tell $f$ is a smooth immersion restricted to this chart in my answer? After that, you can compute the differential in two more affine charts and get a similar answer. Now to check that $f$ is an embedding, you just need to check that $f$ is injective. But you can check that directly from the definition.

Comment: Being an embedding is a global property, not a local one. There is no additional difficulty in this case, however, since the domain is compact and the codomain is Hausdorff. Nonetheless it might be instructive to figure out what the inverse looks like and why it is continuous.

Comment: I managed to show that f is a smooth immersion in local coordinates by showing that the differential has trivial kernel is each coordinate chart, meaning that it is injective. How do I check that f is a homeomorphism onto its image (so it's a topological embedding as well)?

Comment: You now need to check that $f$ is injective. An injective smooth immersion on a compact manifold is a topological embedding. See for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111112/condition-that-a-local-homeomorphism-be-a-covering-map

Comment: I am still not sure how to check injectivity. So suppose $f[x,y,z]=f[a,b,c]$, say. Then I have to show that $[x,y,z]=[a,b,c]$, but I also need to consider that in projective space points which are scalar multiples of each other are the same.